# ¿Cuál es la causa del error " A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame" en este script?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter

Este script, no me permite actualizar valores de una columna en una dataframe, por que que entiende que la sentencia es una vista del df original, limitada solamente a esa columna.

```
import pandas
import pandas_datareader.data as pdr

start = "2020-1-2"
end = "2021-4-28"
nom_val = "GOOG"
window_fast = 70
window_slow = 200 

datos = pdr.DataReader(nom_val, 'yahoo', start = start, end = end)
datos.rename(columns={"Close":nom_val }, inplace=True)
df = datos[[nom_val]].copy(deep=True)

# Medias móviles exponenciales
df.loc[:, "ewmfast"] = df[nom_val].ewm(window_fast).mean().dropna()
df.loc[:, "ewmlow"] = df[nom_val].ewm(window_slow).mean().dropna() 

# Señales y posición
df["signal"] = 0
df["position"] = 0

for i in range (1, df.shape[0]):
    if (df["signal"][i] == 0) & (df["ewmfast"][i-1] < df["ewmlow"][i-1]) & (df["ewmfast"][i] > df["ewmlow"][i]):
        df["position"][i]= 1   # ¿ entiende que es una vista del df original, limitado solamente a esta columna?
        df["signal"][i] = 0

    if (df["signal"][i] == 1) & (df["ewmfast"][i-1] > df["ewmlow"][i-1]) & (df["ewmfast"][i] < df["ewmlow"][i]):
        df["position"][i] = 0
        df["signal"][i] = 0
```

Me devuelve:

:24: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

```
See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  df["position"] [i]= 1
```

¿Cómo puedo resolver este problema?. Agradeceré ayuda.

Comment: Hola @efueyo. ¿Cual es el objetivo o qué pretendes con esta línea de código?    'df = datos[[nom_val]].copy(deep=True)'

Comment: Hola @Jose Luis Niñomalo. Lo que pretendo es que en las sentencias posteriores de creación de columnas, no me salga el mensje "a value is triying... sea the caveats..", que me vuelve loco en mis scripts. No lo acabo de dominar.

Comment: Este artículo de la documentación de python debería aclarar tus dudas y resolver algun de tus problemas cuando manipulas dataframes y/o sus copias: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

Comment: El link deja claro que la opción "dfd['a'][2] = 111", debe ser evitada por que fallará algunas veces. La opción recomendad  es dfd.loc[2, 'a'] = 11.  Gracias